# Verify solution to first order partial differential equation with If condition and ReplaceAll

Tags: differential-equations, functions, replacement

I am confident the solution to the following differential equation is correct.

$$\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial x}=0$$

**Two Questions:** (1) Does the solution verification (`pde /. sol // FullSimplify`) appear to be constructed correctly? (2) If `True` (or if `False`) why does it always return `Null` (prints as indeterminate)?

```
pde := D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x] == 0
ic := u[0, x] == Exp[-x] Sin[x]^2
bc := u[t, 0] == 0
sol := First[DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[t, x], {t, x}]]
ver := If[pde /. sol // FullSimplify, Style["True", lime], 
  Style["False", Background -> Red], 
  Style["Indeterminate", Black, Background -> Yellow]]
Print[ver]
```

**returns:** `Indeterminate`

**goal:** return `True` or `False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To verify solution of ode or pde, it is better use the form `u` instead of `u[...]` in the call. This makes it return a `Function` which can be used to verify the ode or the pde by direct substitution.

```
pde = D[u[t, x], t] + D[u[t, x], x] == 0
ic = u[0, x] == Exp[-x] Sin[x]^2
bc = u[t, 0] == 0
sol = First@DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u, {t, x}];
(pde /. sol) // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verified

side points. No need to use `:=` for assignments to variables. Simply use `=`

Comment: Thank you so much. This second time you came through for me in less than 24 hours.